# Android WebView Media Output Not Working in App

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to integrate webview which has an audio bot. The bot speaks out the questions. Working in chrome browser and slack web view but not in my app webview.

Have tried below code for media output
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

Here is the sample code

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {
            myRequest = request;

            for (String permission : request.getResources()) {
                switch (permission) {
                    case "android.webkit.resource.AUDIO_CAPTURE": {
                        askForPermission(request.getOrigin().toString(),
                                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Uncaught (in promise) Your browser does not support Speech Synthesis
Uncaught ReferenceError: speechSynthesis is not defined